# ec2_bundle_vol fails with error LoadError

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2

I am a newbie in amazon ec2 setup.

I have now setup a machine to my taste - and I now want to bundle it.

I am running the following command from the launched instance -

```
root@domU-21-34-67-26-ED-Z4:~# ec2-bundle-vol -r i386 -d /mnt \
                              -p ACT-VOL -u 8940-1355-4155 -k /tmp/pk-key.pem \
                              -c /tmp/cert.pem -s 10240 \
                              -e /mnt,/root/.ssh,/home/ubuntu/.ssh

ruby: No such file or directory -- 
 /home/ubuntu/ec2tools/ec2-api-tools-1.3-46266/lib/ec2/amitools/bundlevol.rb (LoadError)
```

The ruby version is 1.8.7. I searched internet and installed libruby1.8-extras etc too,  but to no avail. I also tried running it from site_ruby (/usr/local/lib/site_ruby) - but no use.

I tried installing 1.8.6 version of ruby, but was unable to find a way to do so too.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
K

EDIT: One more question is : Should I be running this command in my local machine or should I run this command in the launched instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've run into the annoying problem that the EC2 AMI tools aren't installed by default on an EC2 instance.  The tools are available via [this link](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/index.html?PreparingAndCreatingAMIs.html) - just download and unzip them onto your launched instance and you should be good to go.

Comment: I am not sure I understood this point. I had downloaded ec2 ami and api tools in the launched instance, and only there I was running this command. So, these tools are there.

Comment: Hmm, I see now that it's not complaining about the actual command.  Can you check that you have the EC2_HOME environment variable set to /home/ubuntu/ec2tools/ec2-api-tools-1.3-46266/ and that your PATH includes $EC2_TOOLS/bin ?

Answer (score 0):

run the script directly from the bin directory in your AMI-tools, NOT in API-tools.
the home path must be set to the AMI-tools path too for the ec2-bundle-vol command

Answer (score 0):

> /home/ubuntu/ec2tools/ec2-api-tools-1.3-46266/lib/ec2/amitools/bundlevol.rb (LoadError)

The first problem I had is that I had set the `EC2_HOME` and `EC2_AMITOOL_HOME` environmental variables to point to the old location of the `ami-tools` in `/opt`.  Removing those exports from my script and my environment and everything worked better.

Initially I also thought it was a problem with an incompatible version of ruby.

The solution for me was to de-install the version of `juby` and to de-install the `ami-tools` package (under ubuntu actually `ec2-ami-tools`).  Then when I reinstalled `ami-tools` package it was able to pick up the appropriate ruby version and everything seemed to now work.

```
apt-get remove ruby
apt-get remove ec2-ami-tools
apt-get install ec2-ami-tools
```